# Gridview doesnt update after the delete command

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Basically, I use objectdatasource with gridview.. Everything works, but the gridview, doesnt update as soon as I click the delete button. This forces me to use Server.Transfer on the gridviews events:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
   //Server.Transfer(~/SamePageAsTheGridview);
}
```

Is there a way for the data to be updated without full post back?

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the selected item from your objectsource, 
Just rebind the data to the gridview after delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{
   GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Ok, how/where are you binding the grid?

Comment: at the event..i put server.Transfer inside the event..it works..i had no choice

Comment: No, I mean how and where are you *initially* binding the grid.  And are you sure the delete is actually happening properly? ie, is it going from the object collection / db (if there is one)

Comment: I have an objectdatasource, it does all the binding for me..i go to the smart tag and choose the object datasource