# Gridview doesn't update in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I delete a row from `GridView`, it doesn't update. 
I looked here also

[Gridview doesnt update after the delete command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662609/gridview-doesnt-update-after-the-delete-command)

there isn't any solution.

here is some my code

```
private void SepettenOgeSil(int p)
{
    SqlDataSource4.DeleteCommand = "Delete from ilker_sevim_sepets where seperID="+ p;
    if (SqlDataSource4.Delete() > 0)
    {
        siparisleriGetir();
        SqlDataSource4.DataBind();
        // Button1_Click(null, null);

        urunFiyatHesapla();
    }
    else
    { 
    }
}

private void urunFiyatHesapla()
{
    int tmpToplamUrunFiyati =0, tmpUAdeti;
    int tmpTekUrunFiyati;
    TextBox t;
    int sayici=0;
    foreach ( GridViewRow item in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        t= (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox2");
        tmpUAdeti = Convert.ToInt32(t.Text);
        tmpTekUrunFiyati =Convert.ToInt32(item.Cells[3].Text);
        tmpToplamUrunFiyati += tmpTekUrunFiyati * tmpUAdeti;
    }

    Label2.Text = tmpToplamUrunFiyati.ToString();
}
```

when I call `urunFiyatHesapla();` method in a button click event, it works. when I bind it to a `GridView` I get an error.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your gridview like this GridView1.DataBind();